# Get each li value with a specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume I have a body such as;

```
<div class="body">
    <ul>
        <li class="01">hi</li>
        <li class="02">bye</li>
        <li class="03">go</li>
    </ul>

    <ul style="">
        <li class="01">hi2</li>
        <li class="02">bye2</li>
        <li class="03">go2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get each `class = "01", class = "02" and class = "03"` values of each `ul`.

What I did so far?

```
$('.body ul').each(function(element)
{
   console.log(this);
});
```

It printed the each li element but how can I reach the values in class 01,02 and 03?

I want to get

hi bye go
hi2 bye2 go2

while looping inside the body

Comment: `$(this).find(".01").text()` to select for that class, or `$(this).children().each(function() { console.log($(this).text();); }`?

Comment: Note that using number alone in class name is not a good idea (might work in some browsers, but might not work in others or in other cases). First character for class name should be letter. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

1. `$("li.02")` - for all `<li>` with class `02`
2. `$(".body>ul>li.02")` - for all `<li>` with class `02` inside a `<ul>`
   inside an element with class `body`.

```js
//for all <li> with class "02"
$('li.02').each(function(element) {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">

  <ul>
    <li class="01">hi</li>
    <li class="02">bye</li>
    <li class="03">go</li>
  </ul>

  <ul style="">
    <li class="01">hi2</li>
    <li class="02">bye2</li>
    <li class="03">go2</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('li.01').text();` returns the string in the element.
If you want to output the strings for each class you can do:

```
$('li.01').each(function(element) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

and for all list items

```
$('li').each(function(element) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```